# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating a library in which depending on the input parameters it is shown as nodes or as a tree.

I have been days trying to solve the problem but it always gives me the same error, when I delete the redux part it loads but if it shows the error "`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`".

I have tried calling redux functions the way you are seeing or using mapStateToProps with mapDispatchToProps.

Since I saw that it was a hooks error, I changed the code from hook to class.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Version Hooks** (I'm using this)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { compose, Dispatch } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import { updateBranchs, updateNumBranchs } from "../../redux/actions/portal";
import {
    updateSelected,
    updateDma,
    updateHiddenBranchs,
} from "../../redux/actions/hierarchy";

import { makeSelectBranchItem, makeSelectHierarchyItem } from "./selectors";

import { generatePortalBranch } from "../../utils/portal";
import {
    replaceHierarchyBranch,
    findDistance,
    findDuplicatedItems,
} from "../../utils/hierarhcy";

import PotalBranch from "../portalbranch";
import HierarchyBranch from "../hierarchybranch";

import { MainProps, IBranch, IHierarchyBranch } from "./interfaces";

const MainTree = ({
    data,
    portal,
    branch,
    hierarchy,
    onUpdateBranchs,
    onUpdateNumBranchs,
    onUpdateSelected,
    onUpdateDma,
    onUpdateHiddenBranchs,
    removeBranchWithChildren,
}: MainProps) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data && !portal) {
            onUpdateBranchs([data]);
        }
    }, [data, portal, onUpdateBranchs]);

    const onUpdatedHiddenBranchs = (ids: Array<string>, show: boolean) => {
        let hiddenBranchs: Array<string> = [...hierarchy.hiddenBranchs];
        let items: Array<string> = [];
        if (!show) {
            items = [...hiddenBranchs, ...ids];
        } else {
            const copyItems: Array<string> = [...hiddenBranchs];
            const duplicatedItems: Array<string> = findDuplicatedItems(
                copyItems
            );
            items = copyItems.filter((item: string) => {
                return !ids.includes(item);
            });
            items = [...items, ...duplicatedItems];
        }
        onUpdateHiddenBranchs(items);
    };

    const onUpdateSelectedBranch = (id: number, dma: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        onUpdateDma(dma);
        onUpdateSelected(id);
    };

    const onUpdateFavourites = (dma: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        let branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...branch.branchs];
        const updatedDma: IHierarchyBranch = Object.assign({}, dma, {
            favourite: !dma.favourite,
        });
        const updated: Array<IHierarchyBranch> = replaceHierarchyBranch(
            branchs,
            updatedDma
        );
        onUpdateBranchs(updated);
        onUpdateDma(dma);
    };

    const updateBranchs = () => {
        let numBranchs: number = branch.numBranchs;
        const branchToUpdate: IBranch = generatePortalBranch(numBranchs);
        let updatedBranchs = [...branch.branchs];
        updatedBranchs.push(branchToUpdate);
        onUpdateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
        onUpdateNumBranchs(numBranchs + 1);
    };

    const renderHierarchyBranch = (index: number, branch: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        const selected: number = hierarchy.selected;
        const hiddenBranchs: Array<string> = [...hierarchy.hiddenBranchs];
        const level: number = findDistance(data, branch.value);
        return (
            <HierarchyBranch
                key={index}
                id={branch.id}
                level={level}
                label={branch.label}
                alarms={branch.value}
                favourite={branch.favourite}
                icon={branch.icon}
                sensorizable={branch.sensorizable}
                children={branch.children}
                branch={branch}
                selectedId={selected}
                hiddenBranchs={hiddenBranchs}
                onUpdateSelectedBranch={onUpdateSelectedBranch}
                onUpdateFavourites={onUpdateFavourites}
                onUpdatedHiddenBranchs={onUpdatedHiddenBranchs}
                renderHierarchyBranch={renderHierarchyBranch}
            />
        );
    };

    const renderPortalBranch = (index: number, branchSelected: IBranch) => {
        const branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...branch.branchs];
        const numBranchs: number = branch.numBranchs;
        return (
            <PotalBranch
                key={index}
                id={branchSelected.id}
                parentId={branchSelected.parentId}
                active={branchSelected.active}
                favorite={branchSelected.favorite}
                level={branchSelected.level}
                title={branchSelected.title}
                editable={branchSelected.editable}
                checkbox={branchSelected.checkbox}
                checkboxEnabled={branchSelected.checkboxEnabled}
                children={branchSelected.children}
                branch={branchSelected}
                branchs={branchs}
                removeBranchWithChildren={removeBranchWithChildren}
                onUpdateBranchs={onUpdateBranchs}
                numBranchs={numBranchs}
                onUpdateNumBranchs={onUpdateNumBranchs}
                renderPortalBranch={renderPortalBranch}
            />
        );
    };

    const renderPortal = () => {
        const branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...branch.branchs];
        return (
            <div className="go-react-tree">
                <div className="go-react-tree__create-button">
                    <i
                        className="icon-plus-squared-alt"
                        onClick={updateBranchs}
                    />
                    <span>Crear nuevo</span>
                </div>
                <div className="go-react-branches">
                    {branchs &&
                        branchs.length > 0 &&
                        branchs.map((branch: IBranch, index: number) => {
                            return renderPortalBranch(index, branch);
                        })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    const renderHierarchy = () => {
        const branchs: Array<IHierarchyBranch> = [...branch.branchs];
        return (
            <div className="go-react-tree">
                <div className="go-react-branches">
                    {branchs &&
                        branchs.length > 0 &&
                        branchs.map(
                            (branch: IHierarchyBranch, index: number) => {
                                return renderHierarchyBranch(index, branch);
                            }
                        )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return portal ? renderPortal() : renderHierarchy();
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    branch: makeSelectBranchItem(),
    hierarchy: makeSelectHierarchyItem(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch) {
    return {
        onUpdateBranchs: (branchs: Array<IBranch>) => {
            dispatch(updateBranchs(branchs));
        },
        onUpdateNumBranchs: (numbranchs: number) => {
            dispatch(updateNumBranchs(numbranchs));
        },
        onUpdateSelected: (id: number) => {
            dispatch(updateSelected(id));
        },
        onUpdateDma: (dma: any) => {
            dispatch(updateDma(dma));
        },
        onUpdateHiddenBranchs: (dmas: any) => {
            dispatch(updateHiddenBranchs(dmas));
        },
        dispatch,
    };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(withConnect)(MainTree);
```

**Version Class Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import HierarchyActions from "../../redux/actions/hierarchy";
import PortalActions from "../../redux/actions/portal";

import { generatePortalBranch } from "../../utils/portal";
import {
    replaceHierarchyBranch,
    findDistance,
    findDuplicatedItems,
} from "../../utils/hierarhcy";

import PotalBranch from "../portalbranch";
import HierarchyBranch from "../hierarchybranch";

import { IBranch, IHierarchyBranch } from "./interfaces";

class MainLibrary extends Component<any, any> {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { data, portal, updateBranchs } = this.props;
        if (data && !portal) {
            updateBranchs([data]);
        }
    }

    onUpdatedHiddenBranchs = (ids: Array<string>, show: boolean) => {
        const { updateHiddenBranchs } = this.props;
        let hiddenBranchs: Array<string> = [...this.props.hiddenBranchs];
        let items: Array<string> = [];
        if (!show) {
            items = [...hiddenBranchs, ...ids];
        } else {
            const copyItems: Array<string> = [...hiddenBranchs];
            const duplicatedItems: Array<string> = findDuplicatedItems(
                copyItems
            );
            items = copyItems.filter((item: string) => {
                return !ids.includes(item);
            });
            items = [...items, ...duplicatedItems];
        }
        updateHiddenBranchs(items);
    };

    onUpdateSelectedBranch = (id: number, dma: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        const { updateDma, updateSelected } = this.props;
        updateDma(dma);
        updateSelected(id);
    };

    onUpdateFavourites = (dma: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        const { updateBranchs, updateDma } = this.props;
        let branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...this.props.branchs];
        const updatedDma: IHierarchyBranch = Object.assign({}, dma, {
            favourite: !dma.favourite,
        });
        const updated: Array<IHierarchyBranch> = replaceHierarchyBranch(
            branchs,
            updatedDma
        );
        updateBranchs(updated);
        updateDma(dma);
    };

    updateBranchs = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { updateBranchs, updateNumBranchs } = this.props;
        let numBranchs: number = this.props.numBranchs;
        const branchToUpdate: IBranch = generatePortalBranch(numBranchs);
        let updatedBranchs = [...this.props.branchs];
        updatedBranchs.push(branchToUpdate);
        updateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
        updateNumBranchs(numBranchs + 1);
    };

    renderHierarchyBranch = (index: number, branch: IHierarchyBranch) => {
        const { data } = this.props;
        const selected: number = this.props.selected;
        const hiddenBranchs: Array<string> = [...this.props.hiddenBranchs];
        const level: number = findDistance(data, branch.value);
        return (
            <HierarchyBranch
                key={index}
                id={branch.id}
                level={level}
                label={branch.label}
                alarms={branch.value}
                favourite={branch.favourite}
                icon={branch.icon}
                sensorizable={branch.sensorizable}
                children={branch.children}
                branch={branch}
                selectedId={selected}
                hiddenBranchs={hiddenBranchs}
                onUpdateSelectedBranch={this.onUpdateSelectedBranch}
                onUpdateFavourites={this.onUpdateFavourites}
                onUpdatedHiddenBranchs={this.onUpdatedHiddenBranchs}
                renderHierarchyBranch={this.renderHierarchyBranch}
            />
        );
    };

    renderPortalBranch = (index: number, branchSelected: IBranch) => {
        const {
            updateBranchs,
            updateNumBranchs,
            removeBranchWithChildren,
        } = this.props;
        const branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...this.props.branchs];
        const numBranchs: number = this.props.numBranchs;
        return (
            <PotalBranch
                key={index}
                id={branchSelected.id}
                parentId={branchSelected.parentId}
                active={branchSelected.active}
                favorite={branchSelected.favorite}
                level={branchSelected.level}
                title={branchSelected.title}
                editable={branchSelected.editable}
                checkbox={branchSelected.checkbox}
                checkboxEnabled={branchSelected.checkboxEnabled}
                children={branchSelected.children}
                branch={branchSelected}
                branchs={branchs}
                removeBranchWithChildren={removeBranchWithChildren}
                onUpdateBranchs={updateBranchs}
                numBranchs={numBranchs}
                onUpdateNumBranchs={updateNumBranchs}
                renderPortalBranch={this.renderPortalBranch}
            />
        );
    };

    renderPortal = () => {
        const branchs: Array<IBranch> = [...this.props.branchs];
        return (
            <div className="go-react-tree">
                <div className="go-react-tree__create-button">
                    <i
                        className="icon-plus-squared-alt"
                        onClick={this.updateBranchs}
                    />
                    <span>Crear nuevo</span>
                </div>
                <div className="go-react-branches">
                    {branchs &&
                        branchs.length > 0 &&
                        branchs.map((branch: IBranch, index: number) => {
                            return this.renderPortalBranch(index, branch);
                        })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    renderHierarchy = () => {
        const branchs: Array<IHierarchyBranch> = [...this.props.branchs];
        return (
            <div className="go-react-tree">
                <div className="go-react-branches">
                    {branchs &&
                        branchs.length > 0 &&
                        branchs.map(
                            (branch: IHierarchyBranch, index: number) => {
                                return this.renderHierarchyBranch(
                                    index,
                                    branch
                                );
                            }
                        )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    render() {
        const { portal } = this.props;
        return portal ? this.renderPortal() : this.renderHierarchy();
    }
}

function selectStateApp(state: any) {
    return {
        numBranchs: state.branch.numBranchs,
        branchs: state.branch.branchs,
        hiddenBranchs: state.hierarchy.hiddenBranchs,
        selected: state.hierarchy.selected,
        selectedDma: state.hierarchy.selectedDma,
    };
}

export default connect(selectStateApp, (dispath) => ({
    updateSelected: (id: number) =>
        HierarchyActions.updateSelected(id)(dispath),
    updateDma: (dma: any) => HierarchyActions.updateDma(dma)(dispath),
    updateHiddenBranchs: (dmas: Array<string>) =>
        HierarchyActions.updateHiddenBranchs(dmas)(dispath),
    updateBranchs: (branchs: Array<IBranch>) =>
        PortalActions.updateBranchs(branchs)(dispath),
    updateNumBranchs: (numBranchs: number) =>
        PortalActions.updateNumBranchs(numBranchs)(dispath),
}))(MainLibrary);
```

Comment: you  need to add `this.` before function names, i.e. `this.updateBranchs([data]);` when you call any particular function from the same class and regarding the error related to hooks, see [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: not, because I'm using const {updateBranch } = this.props

Comment: I've  updated code using hooks and same error

Comment: React and ReactDom should be in peerDependencies for a library,